# Jasper with php help where to place all jar files copied from ireport/modules/ext

Tags: php, report

Im New to jasperreport.

1. Can any one please help me where to copy the jar files from ireport/modules/ext ?
2. Will only the jar files in ireport/modules/ext is enough ?
3. How to connect with php.

Can anyone help me with this please

Comment: this helped me a lot. why you close the question instead of correcting his english a little?

Answer (score 2):

1. Can any one please help me where to copy the jar files from
   ireport/modules/ext ? Will only the jar files in ir

**You have to copy this to your java_home directory. im using windows7 so in my case it will C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext. Make sure you have set the classpath for you java_home. (i hope you know how to do this)**

1. Will only the jar files in ireport/modules/ext is enough ?

**Yes this will do for you**

1. How to connect with php.

Go through the example given below

```
 include('../includes/javabridge.php');
java_set_file_encoding("UTF-8");

// Load the Jasper Report

$jrxml = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader");
$jasperTemplate = $jrxml->load(realpath("customer.jrxml"));

// Load the Query 

$_Query = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignQuery");
$_Query->setText("select * FROM customers");
$jasperTemplate->setQuery($_Query);

// Compile the Report after including the Query

$compile = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager");
$report = $compile->compileReport($jasperTemplate);

// Connect to the database

$class = new JavaClass("java.lang.Class");
$class->forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
$mysqlDriver = new JavaClass("java.sql.DriverManager");
$conn = $mysqlDriver->getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/dbcustomer?user=root&password=");

// Now Fill the Report 
$jasperFill = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager");
$params = new Java("java.util.HashMap");
$params->put("title", "Customer");
$jasperPrint = $jasperFill->fillReport($report, $params, $conn);

// Now Export the Report to desired format 

$jasperExport = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporter");

    // Change here to generate report in pdf , excel,docx etc.. 
$Format = "pdf";

switch ($Format)
{
    case 'xls':
        $outputPath = realpath(".") . "\\" . "output.xls";
        $jasperExport = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter");
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporterParameter")->IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, java("java.lang.Boolean")->TRUE);
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporterParameter")->IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, java("java.lang.Boolean")->FALSE);
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporterParameter")->IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, java("java.lang.Boolean")->TRUE);
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT, $jasperPrint);
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, $outputPath);
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=output.xls");
        break;
    case 'csv':
        $outputPath = realpath(".") . "\\" . "output.csv";
        $jasperExport = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRCsvExporter");
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRCsvExporterParameter")->FIELD_DELIMITER, ",");
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRCsvExporterParameter")->RECORD_DELIMITER, "\n");
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRCsvExporterParameter")->CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT, $jasperPrint);
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, $outputPath);
        header("Content-type: application/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=output.csv");
        break;
    case 'docx':
        $outputPath = realpath(".") . "\\" . "output.docx";
        $jasperExport = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRDocxExporter");
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT, $jasperPrint);
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, $outputPath);
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=output.docx");
        break;
    case 'html':
        $outputPath = realpath(".") . "\\" . "output.html";
        $jasperExport = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRHtmlExporter");
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT, $jasperPrint);
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, $outputPath);
        break;
    case 'pdf':
        $outputPath = realpath(".") . "\\" . "output.pdf";
        $jasperExport = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter");
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT, $jasperPrint);
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, $outputPath);
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=output.pdf");
        break;
    case 'ods':
        $outputPath = realpath(".") . "\\" . "output.ods";
        $jasperExport = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.oasis.JROdsExporter");
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT, $jasperPrint);
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, $outputPath);
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=output.ods");
        break;
    case 'odt':
        $outputPath = realpath(".") . "\\" . "output.odt";
        $jasperExport = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.oasis.JROdtExporter");
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT, $jasperPrint);
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, $outputPath);
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=output.odt");
        break;
    case 'txt':
        $outputPath = realpath(".") . "\\" . "output.txt";
        $jasperExport = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRTextExporter");
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRTextExporterParameter")->PAGE_WIDTH, 120);
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRTextExporterParameter")->PAGE_HEIGHT, 60);
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT, $jasperPrint);
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, $outputPath);
        header("Content-type: text/plain");
        break;
    case 'rtf':
        $outputPath = realpath(".") . "\\" . "output.rtf";
        $jasperExport = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRRtfExporter");
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT, $jasperPrint);
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, $outputPath);
        header("Content-type: application/rtf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=output.rtf");
        break;
    case 'pptx':
         $outputPath = realpath(".") . "\\" . "output.pptx";
        $jasperExport = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRPptxExporter");
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT, $jasperPrint);
        $jasperExport->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, $outputPath);
        header("Content-type: aapplication/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=output.pptx");
      break;
}
$jasperExport->exportReport();

readfile($outputPath);
unlink($outputPath);
```